# How fast does Star Platinum punch?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Star Platinum punches fast. Really fast. MY question is "how fast does Star Platinum punch?" I've heard that he punches at speeds similar to Crazy Diamond, which punches at about 60MPH. Does he punch faster than CD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Physics calculations ahead)**

Background info: Josuke says in episode 29 of DIU that from a certain distance, Crazy Diamond punches at about **60 kilometers/hour** but if he got closer Crazy Diamond could punch at **300km/hour**

In one of the first episodes of Stardust Crusaders, Jotaro takes a revolver pistol to his head about 4.5 inches away and catches it about 1.5 inches away from his head. The initial velocity a bullet would have after being fired from a revolver is 2600 feet/s or 792.48 meters/s and the average acceleration from a pistol is about 440,000 m/s^2.

**Da maths:**

To find the final velocity the bullet had after traveling the 3 inches (0.0762 meters) I used the Physics formula Vf^2 = Vi^2 + 2ad. with Vf being final velocity, Vi being initial velocity, a being acceleration, and d being distance.

Using the formula:

Vf^2 = (792.48 m/s)^2 + 2(440,000 m/s^2)(0.0762 m)

= 628,024.5504 m/s^2 + 2(33,528 m/s^2) = 628,024.5504 m/s^2 + 67,056 m/s^2 = 695,080.5504 m/s^2 square root(Vf^2) = square root(695,080.5504 m/s^2) = 833.7 m/s

Answer: With all these calculations, I found that Star Platinum stopped that bullet while it was travelling at **833.7 meters/s or 0.83 km/s**. Sadly I did all this work for no reason LMAO

heres a link to a quora post: https://www.quora.com/Which-stand-is-faster-Star-Platinum-or-Crazy-Diamond-JoJo

This quora post explains it very simple that when Star Platinum battled Silver Chariot possessed by the Anubis sword, Star Platinum was able to defeat Silver Chariot while one of it's arms was going **double it's usual speed**.

We know that when Silver Chariot defeated Hanged Man, a stand that travels at the speed of light he was also able to predict where it was going and cut it while it was traveling, meaning That when Star Platinum was fighting Silver Chariot, Silver Chariot was stabbing/attacking at **DOUBLE THE SPEED OF LIGHT** meaning that Star Platinum punched faster than **DOUBLE THE SPEED OF LIGHT**. BRUH he's fast. Not to mention that he could also stop time even before he fought Dio without knowing it. So yeah, hoped this helped more than it wasted your time LMAO

Comment: Holy crap, that was a lot. Thank you so much for clarifying this. You deserve waaaaaaaaaay more credit for all this hard work you did.