# If Star Platinum moves as fast as the speed of light, how could Jotaro be hit by N'Doul' stand Geb?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

When Jotaro fought N'Doul, he was capable of hitting Jotaro with his stand. But supposedly only Jotaro and Dio' stands can move as fast as the speed of light.

If Star Platinum moves as fast as the speed of light, how could Jotaro be hit by N'Doul' stand Geb?

Comment: Star Platinum is fast, but I'm struggling to remember when exactly it would have moved at or near a _literal_ light speed. (Excluding times it moved in stopped time.) The fan wiki does refrence this, but cites Part 6 for this, which is quit a bit after Part 3.

Comment: @DJPirtu doesnt him stopping time has to do with the fact he moves at speed of light? According to Physics, supposedly when you approach the speed of light time moves slower, and if you would be able to reach the speed of light time would stop

Comment: Technically, yes. But the reason why I excluded this (and the Part 6 thing) is because at that point of the story, Jotaro is not aware of this ability. He only comes to grips with it while fighting Dio.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Crusaders are in the desert, in Cairo Egypt, and as we know, Egypt is a desert. A hot desert.

The temperature must've been high, causing at least Heat Edema to occur.

Just a few minutes before, all of the Crusaders (except for Joseph, who wasn't going insane, and Iggy, who wasn't even there at that time) were going insane, and they were still recovering, including Jotaro.

So Jotaro was in a weakened state, causing him to not probably be able to move at the speed of light, and Jotaro moves at speeds of about 833.7 meters when he caught the bullet (figured out by Darthplokoon2, thanks bud.) which was probably decreased due to Jotaro recovering from the heat.

Short Answer: Plot

Long Answer: Recovering from a possible Heat Stroke

[How fast does Star Platinum punch?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/61093/how-fast-does-star-platinum-punch)

(^^ Link to the question where I got the speed of SP.)

Answer (score 1):

He didn't go faster than SP. He had started moving before Jotaro, as he already knew that he would punch him, and blocked the area, before Jotaro can react. SP doesn't have foresight, and so can't react to things that happen in the future. Atum, can.